# $\textbf{X}$-measurable set vs measurable set

Tags: measure-theory

According to Bartle's book, The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure, it is written that "Any set in $\textbf{X}$ (measurable space) is called an $\textbf{X}$-measurable set, but when the $\sigma$-algebra $\textbf{X}$ is fixed (as is generally the case), the set is usually be said to be measurable".

I don't really get what "fixed" means. I mean, how could we say a set is measurable when we don't even know what measurable space we're work at? Measurable is clearly a relative terminology, isn't it? and what about measurable function?
However, all examples below the statement specifies the measurable space it is working at.

I am completely lost, please help me

Comment: It means that when there is no chance of confusion, one often omits  specifying what sigma-algebra measurability is with respect to. So for instance, you may say: Let $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ be a measurable space and let $A$ be a measurable or let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be Borel-measurable even though it would be more correct to say that $A$ should be $\mathcal{E}$-measurable and that $f$ should be $(\mathcal{E},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel sigma-algebra-

Comment: @stefan-hansen: Dear Stefan, I still cannot get what you mean. When we say a set is measurable, does it always measurable in any measurable space (contained in any possible $\sigma$-algebra)? So, do you mean that we are only allowed to say a set just as "measurable" instead of "$\textbf{x}$-measurable" if the set is measurable for any possible measurable space?

Comment: When we say that a set is measurable (without mentioning any sigma-algebra), then it should be obvious with respect to what sigma-algebra we mean. Otherwise we should explicitly state which sigma-algebra it is with respect to, i.e. say that it is $\mathbf{X}$-measurable.

Answer (score 1):

What it means is that "measurable", like many math phrases, is shorthand for "$X$-measurable" for whatever measure space $X$ you are talking about.  You must infer the space from the context.

As an analogy, recall that whether a set is "closed" or "open" really depends on what topology we are working in.  So why don't we always say "$\mathcal{T}$-closed" or "$\mathcal{T}$-open"?  Because it's easier to just say "closed" and "open", and usually it is obvious what topology (or metric space) we are talking about.  We only need to specify the topology if we are talking about multiple topologies at once.

The thing you are confused about is that **"measurable" is an inherently ambiguous term**.  It doesn't mean anything by itself.  It is what mathematicians say because **the measure space is understood.**

If you encounter the term "measurable", look through the preceding paragraph for a measure space.  Once you have found the measure space $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$, replace all instances of "measurable" with "$X$-measurable".

Comment: Dear Goos, so if we want to show that a set or a function is measurable, we need to construct a $\sigma$-algebra which makes the set or the function measurable, don't we?

Comment: @barrymikhael No.  I will update my answer.

Comment: Dear goos, In case of lebesgue integral, it is written that the integral is defined on measurable function $f$ over measurable set $E$ with respect to measure $\mu$, without any further explanation. So, what is the $\sigma$-algebra and measure which are used in this definition?

Comment: @barrymikhael The $\sigma$-algebra is the set of Lebesgue-measurable sets.  Since you are talking about the Lebesgue measure $\mu$ you are expected to infer that the sets are the Lebesgue measurable sets.